# Display dependent item dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that contains a parent question and a dependent question.
Dependent question needs to be hidden by default. If the parent question is answered as "Yes", then the dependent question should be shown. 
The dependent question contains the parent question id.

The object structure is as follows.

```
{
  "module_question_id": "e04f487b-4782-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
  "question": "Parent question",
  "question_type": "boolean",
  "is_required": 1,
  "dependant_answer_id": null,
  "parent_question_id": null,
  "answers": [
    {
      "module_answer_id": "ec52835f-4782-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "module_answer_id": "f26a2fa0-4782-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "No"
    },
    {
      "module_answer_id": "521f5e95-534c-11e8-9c0a-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "I don't know"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "module_question_id": "5a71221b-4795-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
  "question": "Dependent question",
  "question_type": "boolean",
  "is_required": 0,
  "dependant_answer_id": "ec52835f-4782-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
  "parent_question_id": "e04f487b-4782-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
  "answers": [
    {
      "module_answer_id": "66d94086-4795-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "module_answer_id": "6a397737-4795-11e8-a89b-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "No"
    },
    {
      "module_answer_id": "1667b12f-534d-11e8-9c0a-408d5ce49fe0",
      "answer": "I don't know"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have hidden the dependant question on page load as follows.

```
 <div className={this.getWrapperClass()}>
      ...
</div>
  getWrapperClass() {
    let wrapperClsName = this.props.questionInfo.parent_question_id == null ? `wrap-${this.props.questionInfo.question_type}` : `hide wrap-${this.props.questionInfo.question_type}`;
    return wrapperClsName;
  }
```

Now i need to show the dependent question when "Yes" is selected on parent question.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing and hiding with a class isn't how you'd normally do this in React. Instead, you'd either render the question, or not, based on state.

Here's a quick example, see the in-snippet comments:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // Initial state: Not showing
    this.state = {
      showingQuestion: false
    };
    
    // Event handler for checkbox
    this.tickBox = event => {
      this.setState({
        showingQuestion: event.currentTarget.checked
      });
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    // Render our UI for whether to show the question, and render
    // the question *if* our state is that we're showing it
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Show the question
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.tickBox} />
        </label>
        {this.state.showingQuestion &&
          <div>
            This is the question
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This is the bit that conditionally renders the question based on the flag in the state:

```
{this.state.showingQuestion &&
  <div>
    This is the question
  </div>
}
```